# Running Apache with mod_wsgi and Flask

Tags: python, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

Getting ImportError while running a Flask app in Apache2 using `mod_wsgi`.

```
[Mon Jun 13 23:54:47.988630 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 1850] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     __import__('werkzeug.exceptions')
[Mon Jun 13 23:54:47.988638 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 1850] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/Users/dr/.virtualenvs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/exceptions.py", line 71, in <module>
[Mon Jun 13 23:54:47.988759 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 1850] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     from werkzeug.wrappers import Response
[Mon Jun 13 23:54:47.988767 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 1850] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/Users/dr/.virtualenvs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 26, in <module>
[Mon Jun 13 23:54:47.989193 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 1850] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     from werkzeug.http import HTTP_STATUS_CODES, \\
[Mon Jun 13 23:54:47.989202 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 1850] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/Users/dr/.virtualenvs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/http.py", line 28, in <module>
[Mon Jun 13 23:54:47.989421 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 1850] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     from urllib.request import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
[Mon Jun 13 23:54:47.989438 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 1850] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] ImportError: No module named request
```

Comment: it seems that you have a package that uses imports for python 3, the module [`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) in python 2 was tranfered into `urllib.request` and `urllib.error` in python 3.  If you get the version of `werkzeug` for python 2 you will likely solve your issue.

Comment: The issue could be that the mod_wsgi version is compiled for Python 3, but a Python 2 virtual environment is being used. There is no specific Python 2 version of  Werkzeug, it handles both 2 and 3, so only way it can be trying to use Python 3 variant of import is that mod_wsgi is compiled for Python 3.

Comment: Checked the werkzeug http file It has this block of code. Don't think it is due to python2 vs 3 thing. Could be a virtualenv issue: try:
    from urllib2 import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
except ImportError:  # pragma: no cover
    from urllib.request import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header

Comment: Please post your code